# iOS 7 Lock Screen's background audio progress bar no longer working

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, ios7

So I'm updating my app to iOS 7 and the progress bar on the lock screen no longer updates, it remains at 0:00 throughout the length of the audio being played.

I'm scouring every corner I can find for anyone else that experienced this problem, dealt with it, but am coming up absolutely empty. I'd give more details if I could, but I'm stumped as to where to begin with this one.

Anyone else seen this, any idea where to start digging?

Comment: I'm finding surprisingly little info on the lock screen progress bar at all...  Could you share how you set it up in the first place?

Comment: Very briefly, just make a dictionary containing the keys you want (such as MPMediaItemPropertyTitle, MPPediaItemPropertyArtist, etc.), then set [MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter].nowPlayingInfo to your dictionary :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, found it. All I had to do was explicitly set `MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate` and it's happy.

Comment: Did you set it to 1? I also came across this problem, setting it to 1 still doesnt set up the background audio progress, which other stuff did you add to the nowPlayingInfo dictionary?

Comment: Yeah, set it to 1.0f, and it worked fine. I added basically everything else too.

Comment: I set duration and playbackRate to NowPlayingInfo, but seek bar doesn't even show on iOS7. Have you experienced this issue? Thanks.